# What does +<str_name> + in mysql-python signify?

Tags: python, mysql-python

Consider the code:

```
mycursor.execute("insert into patients values('"+str(patient)+"','"+name+"','"+age+"','"+gender+"','"+date+"')")
```

--where patient, name, age, gender, date are variables

I have 3 questions:

What are there two +  here?
Why are there two quotes (single and double) here?

Is there any alternative for this code(without using +)?

Comment: + operator is used just to concatenate the strings. preferable to use string formatting https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#string-formatting , it is more readable

Comment: Using `+` on SQL strings leads to SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: Sayse can you please rewrite the code. I would be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `+` in your code is nothing specific to MySQL. It is used to concatenate Python strings together. You need two quotes because one (the single quote) is used to delimit the SQL string, and the other (the double quote) delimits the Python string.

```py
>>> name = "john"
>>> age = 55
>>> "insert into people values ('"+name+"', '"+str(age)+"')"
"insert into people values ('john', '55')"
```

However, you should NEVER, EVER use string concatenation for SQL queries. It makes you vulnerable to what's known as SQL injection, where you can manipulate the query to, for example, make it delete entries instead of inserting.

```py
>>> name = "'); drop table people; --"
>>> age = ""
>>> "insert into people values ('"+name+"', '"+str(age)+"')"
"insert into people values (''); drop table people; --', '')"
```

([obligatory XKCD](https://xkcd.com/327/))

Instead, you should use the syntax your database driver library provides to safely insert values in your query. In Python, your code could be rewritten as:

```py
mycursor.execute("insert into patients values(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", (str(patient), name, age, gender, date))
```

Comment: Thanks Altareos. Why are there 2 plus in the code. The general syntax is <string1> + <string2> in concatenation , why is +<string1>+<string2>+

Comment: @VaiMan `"insert into patients values('"` is also a string. Just like you would do `1 + num1 + num2 + 3` with numbers, you need to do `"abc" + str1 + str2 + "def"` with strings.

Comment: Also can you please remove the + for this code mycursor.execute("update sno set patient='"+str(patient)+"'")

Comment: It works in the exact same way, replace the concatenation with %s and add it as a tuple after the query: `mycursor.execute("update sno set patient=%s", (str(patient),))`